# Why do the vertices in the resulting multigraph have even degree?

Tags: graph-theory, multigraphs

Suppose G(V,E) is a multigraph(i.e. we can have parallel edges in the graph) which contains a cycle C and for all vertices $v \in V$ we have that $deg(v)$ is even.

Now suppose that we remove C from G to obtain G'(V',E').

Why is it the cases that all of the remaining vertices still have even degree?

I understand that if v was not in C then it's degree is unchanged but what if v was adjacent(with one edge) to a vertex u in C?
Surely then v would be left with an odd degree?

Comment: If $v$ is in $C$, how many edges of $C$ are incident at $v$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott at least two?

Comment: That’s true, but you can say even more than that. If you traverse a cycle, can you pass through a vertex more than once?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, No you cannot... so it must be that the degree is exactly two?

Comment: Yes, now you’ve got it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you. So the vertices in the cycle(and the edges of the cycle) have not actually been "deleted from the graph" ?

Comment: I’m interpreting it to mean that the edges of the cycle are deleted, but not the vertices. If one were also to delete the vertices, the result would be false.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott also is it not possible to have a vertex thats not in the cycle but adjacent to a vertex that is in the cycle? I've tried to construct an example of this for myself but it's proving non trivial...

Comment: Yes, it is: look at the [butterfly graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_graph) (also known as the bow tie graph).